# CMAKE: find a shared(module) library

Tags: cmake

Why this statement works if *mylib* is a static library and does not work if it's a dynamic(shared) one:

```
find_library(_found mylib PATHS ${mydirs})
```

where *mydir* keeps a list of directories, containing libraries (static and shared).

I'd like to find a dynamic library in the same manner as it is done for the static libraries (in order to get it close to the executable). There would be a list of directories but for simplicity sake, first this must be made working with a trivial test case:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.21)

project(myproj)

add_executable(myproj main.cpp)
    
find_library(a a${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX} PATHS "c:/work/libs/debug")
find_library(b b${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX} PATHS "c:/work/libs/debug")

message("dll=" "${CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}")
message("dll=" "${CMAKE_STATIC_LIBRARY_SUFFIX}")

message("a=" "${a}")
message("b=" "${b}")
```

And, the directory structure is as this:

```
c:/work (CMakeLists.txt_main.cpp)
   \_libs
        \_debug (a.lib b.dll)
         \_release (a.lib b.dll)
```

The output:

```
1>a=C:/work/libs/debug/a.lib
1>b=b-NOTFOUND
1>dll=.dll
1>dll=.lib
```

Anything?

Comment: `find_library` should be able to find both static and shared libraries. Probably, something wrong with your parameters to that command, or you have unusual name for your shared library. Please, provide more detailed code about your attempt. Preferably, it should be a [mcve].

Comment: @Tsyvarev I have updated my question with a minimal example

Comment: So it find `c:/work/libs/debug/b.dll` if you search for `b.dll` but cannot find it if you search for just `b`. Am I correctly understand your edits? Despite what is written in the documentation for variable [CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_FIND_LIBRARY_SUFFIXES.html), this variable doesn't contain `.dll`. This is because `find_library` searches for the library to be passed to the **linker**, and for link with shared library you need pass to the linker a `.lib` library, which is known as **import library**.

Comment: If you want to find dlls for non-linking purposes, then just search for the file with extension (`b.dll`). (On Linux search for `b` would find `b.so`, because it can be passed to the linker. But on Linux one needn't to copy `.so` near the executable. That is, your problem is Windows-specific and you don't need cross-platform solutions for resolve it.)

Comment: @Tsyvarev, nope. It fails with  c:/work/libs/debug/b.dll as well. And I can use variables to expand the suffix for portable solution.

Comment: You could run `cmake` with additional `--debug-find` option, so `find_library` will print what it actually searches and where.

Comment: @Tsyvarev, find_library considered the following locations:
    C:/work/libs/debug/()b.dll(\.lib) . Could it be reason it can't find?

Comment: So path `C:/work/libs/debug/b.dll` matches to the search pattern of `find_library`. Do you **actually** have a file with given path?

Comment: @Tsyvarev, ls C:\work\_build>ls C:/work/libs/debug/b.dll
C:/work/libs/debug/b.dll